# Rich Text Editor for posts on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I am currently using version 4.2. I want to see the rich text editor (headings drop down menu, underlining, text colours etc.) **when I am editing my posts**. I see that in a few tutorials, [like this](http://www.copyblogger.com/formatting-wordpress-posts/) one and yet cannot get it on my WordPress.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPres comes with Rich text editor is by default.
You can see in first image.

And if it's disabled by any reason you can re-enable it by un-checking "Visual Editor" option and clicking save. (refer image 2)

### UPDATE

Display kitchen Sink  (refer image 3)

[image: visual editor]
[image: visual editor option in profile page]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the first image shows what I currently see. But I think I am missing some options. If you see the link I posted on my question, it shows more tools like Heading for example. Where are these?

Comment: that's called kitchen sink by wordpress, click on last icon it will open it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel a little wiser and a lot more stupid ;-)

Comment: Welcome :) , 
it's common for newbies. not to worry :)